# Пошаговая отладка

Tags: c++, winapi

Выполняю пошаговую отладку. Вот тут попадают в бесконечный цикл ловли сообщений. Как попасть в тот код который отправляет сюда сообщения?

```
void CRenderDevice::message_loop()
    {
        if (editor())
        {
            message_loop_editor();
            return;
        }
        MSG msg;
        PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0U, 0U, PM_NOREMOVE);
        while (msg.message != WM_QUIT)
        {
            if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0U, 0U, PM_REMOVE))
            {
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessage(&msg);
                continue;
            }

            on_idle();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Автоматически никак, только анализ программы вручную.

У вас в почтовом ящике лежит письмо. Как выглядел почтальон, который его принёс? Ваша проблема того же порядка.

В очередь сообщений могут прийти сообщения откуда угодно. Даже любое внешнее приложение имеет возможность запостить в вашу очередь сообщений своё сообщение. Сообщение *уже* лежит в вашем ящике (очереди сообщений), почтальон давно ушёл (тот участок кода, который посылал сообщение, давно отработал).

Вам придётся порыться по всей программе, и выяснить, откуда в принципе может приходить данное сообщение. Проблема осложняется тем, что некоторые сообщения посылаются вам автоматически, так что код, который реально их посылает, находится в глубине user32.dll, а код, который на самом деле был причиной отправки сообщения, может быть где угодно.